# Force Fragment refresh on tab change

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have two tabs. In the second one I have a SeekBar and a save button. When the save button is pressed, I save the SeekBar value and switch to the first tab using this in the save button click listener.

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
```

The Fragment at the position 0 has a ListView that gets values from SQLite database. That's the place where the SeekBar value was saved in the second Fragment. How do I make this Fragment refresh when the save button is pressed so that the changes are shown?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make this Fragment refresh when the save button is pressed so that the changes are shown?

Just tell it to do that using interface of your design this fragment should implement.

```
mySecondFragment.refreshStuffPlease();
```

Answer (score 0):

On tab press call the `notifyDatasetChanged` method of Base adapter of the `ListView`.

```
listadapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
```